# Error on surefire plug in when updating java 8 to 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Getting error "Failed to execute goal" when updating from java 8 to java 11. Updating surefire plugin version to most recent 3.0.0-Mx does not help. This happening when updating source/target/release in mvn plugin

Comment: Can you share the error stacktrace?

Comment: More information would be very helpful... also the pom file including the maven versions etc.